# Object inaccessible due to it's protection level when referencing a member in an C# MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The Index() method of my controller references a type (ExternalSourceProvider) that's specified as a member at the start of the controller:

```
ExternalSourceProvider externalSource;

// GET: Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
    externalSource = new ExternalSourceProvider();
```

I'm getting an error for the ExternalSourceProvider(); on the last line, saying that it's inaccessible due to it's protection level. Here is the definition of ExternalSourceProvider:

```
public class ExternalSourceProvider
{
    ExternalSourceProvider() { }

    public string ExternalSiteAbsoluteURI { get; set; }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to mark the default constructor as public.

```
public class ExternalSourceProvider
{
    public ExternalSourceProvider() { }

    public string ExternalSiteAbsoluteURI { get; set; }
}
```

As it is now, it can't be accessed here

```
externalSource = new ExternalSourceProvider();
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought that generally 'public' is the default protection level. Would you please explain why in this case another default was applied?

Comment: No, the default access modifier for methods of a class is private. This holds even for constructors. So, if you don't specify it, the access modifier of a constructor would be private. By the way there is a nice article regarding private constructors https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcfb85a6.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Your default constructor is `private` (the default accessibility for a class member if none is specified) so there's no way to construct the object.  Make it `public`:

```
public ExternalSourceProvider() { }
```

You could also make it `internal` if you only want other types within the same assembly to construct the type, but *generally* a public class should have at least one public constructor.